# image not found from storage/uploads folder Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

my laravel app root folder is public and image uploaded on storage/uploads folder. when i upload image to storage/uploads/user-image/rabiul.jpg then image has been saved but not show  when call in image url example: , show error not foun

Comment: Hello Rabiul, Welcome to Stackoverflow. you should show your effort to solve this problem basically sharing code and what did you  try so far, here is a link on how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. regarding the error you are facing. i suggest you read more information on the difference between public an storage folder. if your image is the storage folder it cannot be accessed publicly (using link) read this for more info https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: please show some code... also remember to run `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: Your root folder is public? So I can access all your config files and .env files including database password information etc? Only the `public` folder should be public. You have a security problem here. Solve that first before solving the images not being loaded I suggest.